# BitmapImage throwing NotSupportedException on EndInit()

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmapimage

I am trying to create an Image in WPF out of a base 64 string, however, whenever I try to create the BitmapImage for the images Source property, I get a NotSupportedException.

Code:

```
public ScreenCaptureWindow(string screenCaptureBase64) {
    InitializeComponent();
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(screenCaptureBase64);
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
    bitmapImage.EndInit(); //Crashes here
    image.Source = bitmapImage;
}
```

[Link to stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/mabNXqDm)

Attached is a screenshot of the exception details.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: The message says "_No imaging component suitable to complete the operation was found_."  That means it can't figure out what to use to decode the parameter.  Where did the parameter come from, like what file type was it before it was encoded?

Comment: In that case did you try using a [PngBitmapDecoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapdecoder(v=vs.110).aspx) to decode the image?